# TextView that scrolls with the selected item on an Horizontal RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have to show a list of days on a Horizontal RecyclerView and the full date (TextView) under the selected day that scrolls with the RecyclerView.

I tried to add a TextView on a HorizontalScrollView under the RecyclerView but the scroll is not synchronized. I tried also to add a TextView on the RecyclerViewItem but the date is clipped because the RecyclerView item must have a fixed width.

```xml
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/command_left_layout">

        <include
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                layout="@layout/view_tracker_activity" />

        <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/horizontalLayout"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/horizontalTextView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Thursay, Apr 2019"/>

            </RelativeLayout>


        </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Expected behavior :

[Expected behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAs2Y.png)

Comment: Hi! Can you please describe your expected behaviour a little clearer for those who can not access the image?

Comment: I have a Horizontal RecyclerView containing days (Number) as items. I have to show the date (eg. Thursday, Apr 2019) under the selected day. The date must scrolls and stay under the selected day when we scroll on the RecyclerView.

Comment: https://a.imge.to/2019/06/14/PwH8j.png